# linear approximation in point $(0,\ldots,0)$ for $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)= e^{-x_1}+\cdots +e^{-x_n}$

Tags: matrices, analysis, contest-math

hello i dont really know how to do this linear approximation for the function *$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)= e^{-x_1}+\cdots +e^{-x_n}$ in point $(0,\ldots,0)$*
please help me
i started with  i know how to do it for endless functions but in this case i dont know how to do it maybe with the hesse **matrix**?

Comment: Could you do it for the case $n=1$? What do you expect for higher $n$'s?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant but you have the following fact : $x+1\leq e^x \quad\forall x\in(-\infty,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multivariate calculus we have the standard formula
$$f({\bf x})=f({\bf 0})+\nabla f({\bf 0})\cdot{\bf x}+o\bigl(|{\bf x}|\bigr)\qquad({\bf x}\to{\bf 0})\ .$$
For your function $f$ one computes
$$f({\bf 0})=n,\qquad\nabla f({\bf 0})=(-1,-1,\ldots,-1)\ .$$
It follows that the linear approximation of $f$ near ${\bf 0}$ is
$$f_{\rm lin}({\bf x})=n-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\ .$$